# How to fit image into table cell by height with CSS (where the height is not defined explicitly)

Tags: html, css

I have a table. The height of it comes as a size of content. The first cell in a row has a text and it defines the height. The second cell in a row have an image. The image should be fitted (shrunk) into the height of the row.

This is what I need

[image]

What I've made is working in Chrome but it is not working in IE, please have a look.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynewbox/00dq3rsr/1/)

```css
#t{
   background: aliceblue;
   display: table;       
  }
  .r{
   display:table-row;
  }
  .c{
   display:table-cell;
   border:solid black 1px;
   background: aqua;
   vertical-align: middle;
   position: relative;   
  }
  #i{
   height: 100%;       
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div id='t'>
  <div class='r '>
   <div class='c'>
    a<br>
    b<br>
    c<br>
    d<br>
    e<br>
    f<br>
   </div>
   <div class='c'>
    <img id="i" src="http://www.cnc3.co.tt/sites/default/files/content/Glee.png">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to put picture as a background.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynewbox/rm7jf6x4/5/)

```css
#t{
   background: aliceblue;
   display: table;
   width: 300px;
  }
  .r{
   display:table-row;
  }
  .c{
   display:table-cell;
   border:solid black 1px;
   background: aqua;
   vertical-align: middle;
   position: relative;
            width:50%;
  }
  #i{
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
  }

#img_cell{
 background-image: url("http://www.cnc3.co.tt/sites/default/files/content/Glee.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center; 
 background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id='t'>
  <div class='r '>
   <div class='c'>
    a<br>
    b<br>
    c<br>
    d<br>
    e<br>
    f<br>
   </div>
   <div id='img_cell' class='c'>
            </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To fit an image into a table cell by its height using CSS, while not explicitly defining the height, you can use a combination of CSS properties like max-height, width, and object-fit. Here's a step-by-step solution with an example:

Let's assume you have an HTML table like this:

```css
/* Set a class for the table cell containing the image */
.image-cell {
    width: 1%; /* Helps to make the cell size according to the content */
}

/* Style the image within the cell */
.image-cell img {
    max-height: 100%; /* Make the image fit the cell's height */
    width: auto; /* Maintain the image's aspect ratio */
    display: block; /* Remove any extra spacing */
    margin: 0 auto; /* Center the image horizontally */
    object-fit: contain; /* Fit the image while preserving aspect ratio */
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="image-cell">
            <img src="your-image-source" alt="Image">
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- Other content -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Explanation:

We assign a class image-cell to the table cell containing the image. The width: 1%; rule ensures that the cell sizes itself based on its content.
For the image inside the cell, max-height: 100%; ensures the image fits the cell's height while maintaining its aspect ratio.
width: auto; maintains the image's original aspect ratio.
display: block; and margin: 0 auto; are used to center the image horizontally within the cell.
object-fit: contain; ensures the image fits the container while preserving its aspect ratio.
This solution ensures that the image inside the table cell will fit its height while maintaining its aspect ratio. The table cell will adjust its width to accommodate the image.

Remember to replace "your-image-source" with the actual source of your image.

With this approach, the image will fit into the table cell's height without explicitly defining the height, making it responsive and visually pleasing across different devices and screen sizes.

Answer (score -1):

```
img {max-width:100%;max-height:100%;}
```

This makes sure that the image wont get bigger than the parent, in this case, the table cell.

Comment: Sadly, It is not working in IE as long as you did not set up a height for a parent. And I have no height for a parent because the height of a row comes from the height of the first cell, and the first cell takes its height depending on amount of content in it. So, your answer is not helping. I expected it was clear from the question.